# Sending UDP messages from different threads, C language

Tags: linux, c, udp, multithreading

I am running a system that has 5 threads, all threads send UDP messages to the same IP and PORT concurrently.

How does linux handle this? Is there any risk to receive mixed messages? I am using **sendto** function to send udp messages.

many thanks

Comment: Linux doesn't perform synchronization for you. You need to implement some sort of IPC mechanism between threads or synchronization using semaphore or mutexes.

Comment: With UDP you can have any random order of the packets anyway.

Comment: You can even receive UDP messages at the port from different PCs. You don't have any chance to get them in a specific order.

Comment: 1. `sendto()` is a system call, and all system calls are atomic. 2. UDP is a datagram protocol, and datagrams are atomic. Unclear therefore what 'mixed messages' even means.

Comment: Does each thread have its own socket or do they all share the same socket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does linux handle this?

It handles it just fine.

> Is there any risk to receive mixed messages?

It's unclear what you mean by 'mixed messages'.  As is always the case with UDP, there is no guarantee that the packets will arrive at the destination port in any particular order, and there is no guarantee that they will arrive at all -- but if they do arrive, the data in each packet received will identical to the data in a packet that was previously sent.   In particular, you don't have to worry about receiving a packet e.g. that contains half of the data from one packet and half of the data from another packet.

Answer (score 0):

UDP is a means of delivering a single packet *unreliably*, in that, it makes no guarantee of delivery order or even if the packet is received at all.

If you need to send data reliably and in order, use TCP, that's what it's for. ;)